# command not found: sudo wget http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_{CHROME_VERSION}_amd64

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

What could be the reason for this code block not working?

```
sudo: wget http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_{version}_amd64.
deb : command not found
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`deb : command not found` it seems like you're on a debian system. It may be possible that your user doesn't have sufficient privileges to execute the `sudo` command.

Also, I think by default `sudo` is not installed on debian systems. You can use the following [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425664/247378) to install `sudo`.